# Money formatted numbers without using Money data type

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I could cast the number to money format and then convert to varchar, but that will give me max 4 decimal places. I need upto 5 decimal places. How can I do it?

Comment: Why dont you use numeric or decimal datatype of sql server??

Comment: See, I have a decimal number with 5 decimal places. Now I need to convert it into comma separated form. If I use money while converting, I'll get only upto 4 decimal places.

Comment: Formatting is a job for the presentation layer, not SQL. Use the precision required to store the number accurately and worry about how it will be formatted later.

Comment: @GarethD Well, say I'm working on presentation layer. Can you please provide me the solution?

Comment: It would depend what your presentation layer is? SSRS? c#.net? etc.